# Django. right way for sorting?

Tags: sql, django

I have 3 tables :

```
class Specialist(models.Model) :
    rating = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

class Service(models.Model) :
    parent_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class SpecialistPrice(models.Model) :
    specialist = models.ForeignKey(Specialist, related_name='price')
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, related_name='service')
    price_bottom = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

And I need to sort specialists by **minimum** of `SpecialistPrice.price_bottom` and where `SpecialistPrice.service.parent_id=0` and 2nd sort condition `-rating`

I need an advice.

**UPD**
I have made:

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(min_price=Min('price__price_bottom')).order_by('min_price', '-rating')
```

But got error

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'min_price' into field.
```

Raw sql is working fine.

```
 SELECT `specialist`.`id`, `specialist`.`rating`,MIN(`specialistprice`.`price_bottom`) AS `min_price` FROM `specialist` LEFT OUTER JOIN `specialistprice` ON ( `specialist`.`id` = `specialistprice`.`specialist_id` )  GROUP BY `specialist`.`id` ORDER BY `min_price` ASC, `rating` DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).
This query should work for you:

```
Specialist.objects.filter(price__service__parent_id=0).order_by('price', '-rating')
```

Comment: @isle2005 look UPD pls.
I need minimum of all speliastprice.price_bottom for each specialist